# How to use pandas to_csv float_format?

Tags: python, pandas, string.format

I am reading from a data file that has 8 precision, then after interpolating some values I am saving them like where the float_format option is not working,

```
df.to_csv('data.dat',sep=' ', index=False, header=False, float_format="%.8f")
```

and the result file looks like

```
0.02506602 0.05754493 0.36854688
0.02461631 0.0599653 0.43078098
0.02502534 0.06209149 0.44955311
0.4267356675182389 0.1718682822340447 0.5391386354945895
0.426701667727433 0.17191008887193007 0.5391897818631616
0.4266676661681287 0.17195189807522643 0.5392409104354972
```

The first 3 lines were in data file and next 3 are the new interpolated values. I want all the values to be of same length. Whats going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Also: It would be nice if I can control the float precision differently for different columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Most likely, there is an issue with your input data. Use `pd.DataFrame.dtypes` to check all your input series are of type `float`. If they aren't convert to `float` via:

```
df[col_list] = df[col_list].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float').fillna(0)
```

Here's a working example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""0.02506602 0.05754493 0.36854688
0.02461631 0.0599653 0.43078098
0.02502534 0.06209149 0.44955311
0.4267356675182389 0.1718682822340447 0.5391386354945895
0.426701667727433 0.17191008887193007 0.5391897818631616
0.4266676661681287 0.17195189807522643 0.5392409104354972""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

print(df.dtypes)

# 0    float64
# 1    float64
# 2    float64
# dtype: object

file_loc = r'C:\temp\test.dat'
df.to_csv(file_loc, sep=' ', index=False, header=False, float_format="%.8f")

df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

print(df[0].iloc[-1])

# 0.42666767
```

Comment: well somwhere along the way I have used a code `df.loc[df[col1]==some_value]=''` that messed up everything

Comment: @Eular, Yes, that could be it. Not sure why you'd add empty strings to numeric data. Use `np.nan` instead and you might have better luck.

Comment: `print an empty line in some places` - that's non-trivial (and inefficient). I strongly advise against. I think you probably need to provide a [mcve]. Because (as you can see from my example), it's not straightforward to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, float_format working now. Thanks. Can you set the precision as 2 point for 1st column and 8 point for later 2?

Comment: @Eular, I'm not sure this is possible with `to_csv`. You may wish to start a new question.

Comment: well, I had one integer column and I wanted to write that as integers but when I use `np.nan` I can't keep the column as integer. Thats why I am trying different precision format for different columns. Also if I use `round()` then some prints in scientific `e` notation I also don't want that. So, my best shot would be using `round()` without introducing `e` notation.

Comment: It's a common problem. `nan` is considered a `float`, but there isn't a substitute for `int` type. Best, in my opinion, to leave as `float`, or some integer (e.g. `-1`) which you know is invalid data. Definitely not a good idea to start rounding and playing around with `object` type.