# pyarrow export csv when floating point precision problem

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

csv.write_csv(table, "animals.csv") when result floating point look like

1.12999999999

Is there a similar pandas export with float_format parameters(data.to_csv(target, index=False,float_format='%g'))?

The reason why you don't use pandas directly is because pyarrow is faster at exporting csv.

A faster way to export csv than pandas and solve the floating point precision problem.

Comment: Is that answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476690/how-to-use-pandas-to-csv-float-format

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dogfood did you find a solution? I stumbled across the same issue. ```pandas.read_csv(…)``` with ```engine="pyarrow"``` sped up reading by a factor of 6, now I'm looking for ways to speed up writing. Didn't figure out yet how to set float precision with ```pyarrow.csv.write_csv(…)``` :/

Comment: For future readers: pyarrow as a write engine for pandas to_csv might soon be implemented, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/54171 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53618